# How to identify partial tuple matches in a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

If I have a dictionary consisting of a list of tuples like so:

```
d = {'ENSG00000186092': [('ENST00000641515', '3'),
                        ('ENST00000641515', '1'),
                        ('ENST00000641515', '2'),
                        ('ENST00000335137', '1')],
    'ENSG00000284662': [('ENST00000332831', '1')],
    'ENSG00000284733': [('ENST00000426406', '1')]}
```

How can I identify if, for each key, there are tuples whereby the first element of the tuples don't match but the second elements do?

For instance, in the above example, we would only see one "hit", and that'd be for the key `ENSG00000186092` because of:

```
('ENST00000641515', '1')
('ENST00000335137', '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Would a convoluted list-comprehension be of interest to you?

```
[
  k for k, v in d.items()
  if any(
    (i, j)
    for i, j in v
    for x, y in v
    if i != x and j == y
  )
]
>>> ['ENSG00000186092']
```

1. Loops over the dictionary
2. Loops over the list of tuples for each key
3. For each tuple, loops through the same list and checks to see that the first entries don't match but the second do
4. If there are any found then record that key from step 2.

Comment: This seems fine to me! If I want the output to be the matching tuples instead of the key, how would I do that?

Comment: Change the item which is stored in the resulting list; this line `k for k, v in d.items()` becomes `v for k, v in d.items()` (or indeed `v for _, v in d.items()`, because `k` isn't used).

Comment: Oh wait, that returns all the tuples for the matching keys.

Comment: You can go over the list and use the keys to pull out the lists of tuples and then do the same logic on them that's inside the `any()` function: `[(i, j) for k in [k for k, v in d.items() if any((i, j) for i, j in v for x, y in v if i != x and j == y)] for i, j in d[k] for x, y in d[k] if i != x and j == y]`. It's really starting to take shape now! A terrible shape.

Comment: Alright, I tried that, and have noticed that I'm getting duplicates in the result, so I tried set-ifying the result but keep getting errors like `unhashable type 'list'`

Comment: `set` uses hash tables underneath so all the elements need to be hashable. To be hashable they have to be immutable and `list` can be modified. Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55388030/736221

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'ENSG00000186092': [('ENST00000641515', '3'),
                        ('ENST00000641515', '1'),
                        ('ENST00000641515', '2'),
                        ('ENST00000335137', '1')],
    'ENSG00000284662': [('ENST00000332831', '1')],
    'ENSG00000284733': [('ENST00000426406', '1')]}

for k, a in d.items():
    a_s = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
    for i in range(len(a_s)-1):
        if a_s[i][1] == a_s[i+1][1] and a_s[i][0] != a_s[i+1][0]:
            print (k, a_s[i], a_s[i+1])
```

- Sort the tuples by second element then by first element of the tuples so that the tuples come together by second element and then by first element
- Check the condition between current tuple and next tuple in the sorted list and print them if condition is met
- **Time Complexity** if `d` has `k` items and list size is 'n' then it is `O(k*nlogn)` [`k` for outer loop and `nlogn` for sorting]

Answer (score 0):

Being very verbose:

```
d = {
    "ENSG00000186092": [
        ("ENST00000641515", "3"),
        ("ENST00000641515", "1"),
        ("ENST00000641515", "2"),
        ("ENST00000335137", "1"),
    ],
    "ENSG00000284662": [("ENST00000332831", "1")],
    "ENSG00000284733": [("ENST00000426406", "1")],
}

def has_duplicates(list_of_tuples):
    seen = set()
    for _, value in list_of_tuples:
        if value in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(value)
    return False

dupes = [key for key, value in d.items() if has_duplicates(value)]

print(dupes)
```

The `has_duplicates` function takes a value from your dictionary. It returns True if any of the tuples in that value have the same second value.

The list comprehension at the return gives you all the keys were `has_duplicates` is True.